# Cannot solving error while using SelectOutputOut block

Tags: anylogic

I am still a beginner at modeling anylogic. I am currently using the selectOutputOut block to create the different routes of agent flow (the agent named product). I already created a function for choosing the output and already inputted the type SelectOutputOut for returning values.

I simply followed the SelectOutputN example from AnyLogic example model. However, there is an error "This method must return a result of type SelectOutputOut" which I really do not know how to fix.

If you have any solutions, please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Here are the images

[image: Block diagram]

[image: Java source of error]

[image: Optionlist]

[image: Parameter embeded in agent(Product)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at the very end of the choosingOutput function body write `return null;`

The problem is that you only have "else if" statements, you need to either write an else statement to cover all the possibilities, or return something at the very end (in case all the ifs are false)

It will also work if your last if, instead of writing if else(agent.product == TypeC), you just write else