# AnyLogic funtion with using SelectOutputOut block and while loop

Tags: if-statement, do-while, anylogic

Good day!
I faced the challenge of writing the function for allocation of the agents into SelectOutputOut blocks. Considering various scenarios of using if...else statements in function I understand that all possibilities must be covered (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50366507/cannot-solving-error-while-using-selectoutputout-block)).
However, the problem is that I don't want the agent to leave the function before it gets the appropriate SelectOutputOut block. This situation may occur if there are not enough resources in any Service blocks (Network1, Network2 or Network3). In this case, it is necessary to wait for any Service block will have enough resources for servicing the agent. For this purpose, I tried to use the while loop, but it doesn't help.
The questions are:

1. How to write the if-else statements to force the agent waits for enough resources in any Service block
2. Does the Select function monitor the parameters which are outside it? In other words: Does it know about the states of Service blocks during its execution?

Thank you.

[image: The system structure]
[image: The properties of the SelectFunction]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is have your agents wait in the queue and then have a function to remove them from the queue and then send them to the correct service block. The best way to do this is with an enter block where you can send them to.

See example below

[image]

You then need to call this function at the `On enter` code for the queue as well as the `On exit` code for the service blocks, to ensure you are always sending new agents when there is space.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I don't understand why we need to call function checkIfAgentCanBerleased in service blocks? It seems that if the conditions in the function are true the agent is allocated to the appropriate Service block. And then it leaves the model.

Comment: Another misunderstanding is connected with if-conditions in the function. You consider the number of agents in the delay block of the Service. Right? What do you suppose to be agent.volume?
I supposed that agent.volume in the Number of Resources from the ResourcePool.

Comment: I think you need to consider doing some of the tutorials and get a basic understanding of the Process Modeling Library.. contact me directly if you need more links and resources.
You need to call the function every time something changes and it needs to check if the next resources need to leave the queue. 

I just used agent.volume as an example because you used it. I thought it was something you wanted to check.